# Add layers to a PSD file using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, psd

I have a lot of JPEG files and I want to add them as layers to a PSD file using ImageMagick

I found several scripts to do the opposite, extract the layers from a PSD file. I don't want that.

I just want to take several JPEG pictures and add them as layers to a PSD (photoshop) file and name those layers as the JPEG file name. I found a way to create composite images with ImageMagick but all the examples I saw create a PNG or GIF file. I need to create a PSD layered file.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes first:

1/ The first layer in a psd file is all the layers merged and you would need to create that first.

2/ For some reason the first layer using the code below drops the first layer e.g image1.png so create a blank layer to use as the first layer.

3/ The layers in my test were renamed to L000001 etc.

The answer to the first part of your question is:

```
convert image1.png image2.png image3.png
```

But I do not know how to keep the image names as the layer names