# How can I specify layer names when writing multi-layer PSD file

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Can imagemagick give layer names to layers when writing multi-layer PSD files?

The only thing I've found on SE is an "I don't know" from nine years ago:
[Add layers to a PSD file using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760590/add-layers-to-a-psd-file-using-imagemagick)

Comment: I do not think ImageMagick can export the layer names. You would have to name them manually.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've come up with so far. I was hoping someone had some secret knowledge to pass on.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are hoping to do, but you could maybe do your processing with **ImageMagick** and modify the resulting layer names with **Python**, https://pypi.org/project/psd-tools/

Comment: @marksetchell Thanks. A little kludgy, but kludgy and automated is better than manual. I hope imagemagick adds this one day.